# How to restore working solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reset

I was working on a C# project and everything works perfectly fine. But after I messed up with a code a little now its getting a wired error. But I can run the last working solution fine. Can I reset the code again to last working solution? If I can, what is the method to do that? 
Here is the error message:

> "Error    1   'Static_calc.Form2' does not contain a definition for
>   'Form2_Load' and no extension method 'Form2_Load' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'Static_calc.Form2' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Why not just use the last working solution?

Comment: Do you use a source control provider such as Team Foundation Server, git or SubVersion?

Comment: no i am just working on my pc. no version controllers. i can use last working solution .I also want to reset my codes back to last working solusion

Comment: Well using the last working solution *is* the best way to reset your codes outside of using source control (TFS, SubVersion, git ... etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like you have deleted a method that your form is rely on in its designer code behind. Take a look in the designer file for Form2 for any event bindings that relate to Form2_Load and delete the line that mentions it.

You should then be able to view the form correctly in the gui and use it as before.

Comment: Wow that is some easy method. thank you its working . C# is seem to be kind of wired

Comment: Its a common problem when deleting a void that is used by a form (be it a click,onload,etc) from the code behind. Studio doesn't remove the binding from the designer file. You also need to remember to remove any bindings you may have manually set e.g. somecontrol.Click += myVoid();  If I helped don't forget to tick the answer!!

Comment: yeah in python we usually do the registering event from hard coding. i guess you mean by .even thought we delete the handler the code itself not deleting the event register because its a separately creating by the system itself right?

Comment: yea something along those lines. It has always surprised me that deleting the method in the code does not unbind it in the designer file. But thats microsoft for you!

Comment: @Optimuskck - Remember that in Windows forms there's a file with the extension .design.cs which holds auto generated code.

Comment: @jamesakadamingo hahha yeah i guess so .thank for the solution pal .really appreciate it :)